# System.MissingMethodException when trying to extract ZipFile from ZipArchive

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, c#-ziparchive

I have a C# .NET (v4.6.2) WinForms app where I'm accessing a file that may/may not be a .zip archive that was created using System.IO.Compression. I have both System.IO.Compression and System.IO.Compress.FileSystem references in the project and referencing System.IO.Compression in the .cs file

I'm getting the error

> "could not read file from disk. (Error: method not found: 'Void
>   system.io.compression.zipfile.extensions.extractToFile(System.IO.Compression.ZipArchiveEntry,
>   system.string)'"

It looks like the issue, based on the error, is in the `ExtractToFile` command, though I can't figure out where to start to fix this.

Below is the code for attempting to open the file as a .zip archive:

```
using (ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(File.OpenRead(zipPath), ZipArchiveMode.Read))
{
    foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries)
    {
        if (entry.FullName.EndsWith(".wco3", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            entry.ExtractToFile(Path.Combine(extractPath, entry.FullName));
        }
    }
    if (File.Exists(DestPath + DestFile))
    {
        Success = Succeeded;                                
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this is the actual error? Because, this: `system.io.compression.zipfile.extensions` doesn't exist. The extension method Is found in `System.IO.Compression.ZipFileExtensions`. If you position the caret on the `ExtractToFile()` method and press F12, what happens?

Comment: Jimi, it goes to the line  
public static void ExtractToFile(this ZipArchiveEntry source, string destinationFileName);

under ZipFileExtensions [from metadata]

Comment: So, the extension method does exist. Is the error reported just a typo, then? Also, the System.IO.Compress**ion**.FileSystem. Try: delete everything in the Project's `obj` sub-folder. The `.vs` folder in the Solution main directory, clean the Solution, rebuild the Solution. Verify you don't have any other extension method anywhere else that references the `ZipArchiveEntry` class. Or some other library you might have tested before, maybe.

Comment: So I verified there are no other extension methods referencing the ZipArchiveEntry class and there aren't. I tried what you said and no change. I know there isn't a typo, as it works on 1 build, but not the platform that I need to deploy the WinForm app.

Comment: Have you tested other compression libraries? Have you checked whether some references to *unknown* assemblies are still present in the Project(s) `References` or in the `[project].csproj` or `packages.config` files?

Comment: @JeffS. you mentioned that code works fine on one PC but not on another. Most likely one of the PCs have the greater version of .NET (f.e. 4.6) and another lower (f.e. 4.0). Can you provide .NET Framework versions for target PCs?

Comment: The .net framework on the target pc is 4.7.1, so in theory that should work. I found a workaround by changing entry.ExtractToFile() to ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory and that seems to work on the development and target computers